# When overriding DynamicObject's TryInvokeMember(), how to choose a correct overload to invoke?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic-language-runtime, dynamicobject, tryinvokemember

How would you implement an algorithm to choose the correct method overload, when overriding the following method on `DynamicObject`?

```
bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
```

Comment: This is a little unclear to me, but The `args` array will be of different length, different types, or both if the name of the member being invoked is the same.

Comment: @vcsjones: just those two aspects, or something more?

Comment: There's a bug with the way out/ref arguments are handled, and its fix did not find its way into SP1.  I am second-guessing myself, thinking there's more to the problem than meets the eye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this overload issue is due to forwarding to statically implemented methods. A solution could  be to just let the dlr do the work for you. Open source [Dynamitey](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey) has a static method that creates all the dlr binding code, caches appropriately and then invokes it and the dlr binder does overload resolution. [example](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey/blob/4f91b3ffb6eba34b1b7bbd212a538e08e501aac2/Dynamitey/DynamicObjects/BaseForwarder.cs#L231). This example handles named/optional params and inferred generics in the overload resolution, however DynamicObject does not expose explict generics or ref out params in the invocation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not straightforward as you have to take into account things like implicit type conversion and variable length parameters (which must be mapped to arrays).

The [MethodCallResolver](http://code.google.com/p/zentrum/source/browse/trunk/source/Zentrum/Zentrum.Dynamic/MethodCallResolver.cs) class in the [Zentrum](http://code.google.com/p/zentrum/) framework provides an example of how to find a matching method.